# NSURLSession not retrieving data from plist file

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I have an iOS application where I get data from a plist file from an amazon s3 server.  I would like to use the new NSURLSession frameworks to get the data.  So I have the following code (which I am using from a Ray Wenderlich dot com tutorial).

```
    NSString *dataUrl = @"https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.plist";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dataUrl];

    // 2
    NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                                          dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                              // 3: Handle response here with more of my code
                                             }];// 4    
[downloadPhotoTask resume];
```

If I copy the URL from *dataURL and put that into a web browser, it downloads the file just fine.  But in my iOS application there is no data and the error is "too few bytes in stream."

Does anybody have an idea of what I am missing?

Comment: You are resuming the wrong task.

Comment: So in your completionHandler (at comment #3) data is nil, and you get an NSError that says too few bytes in stream? Can you post the exact error message, along with info about ` data` and `response`?

Comment: Have you examined what error is within the completionHandler? Also your code is not the same as the Ray Wenderlich code, specifically downloadTask is a local variable. I don't know how it behaves when it goes out of scope, but there's a good chance it will cancel the download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a first look the code itself should work. Did you mean 
`[downloadTask resume];`
by any chance?

Comment: Turned out I was referencing the wrong data stream.  My mistake.  Thank you all for pitching in.

Comment: this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift) using plist file in server side.